# Segue to UIViewController from a xib

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a custom UIView which is a xib file and then a class that controls this view. I also have a storyboard which a lot of different view controllers inside. How do I perform a segue from the UIView to a specific UIViewController that is inside the storyboard?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark top answer and upvote any answer that has solved your issue. others facing the same issue will want to know what solved your problem and those putting in the time to help deserve the rep points

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. What you can do is give the `UIViewController` a storyboard ID, using the menu on the right of the interface builder.

[image]

Then call it programatically, like so:

```
MyCustomViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: tried this and then I get the error "No visible @interface declares the selector presentviewcontroller ......

Comment: @OliBlack I updated the code. `vc` is a reference to a viewController like any other, simply push it the way you normally would without a segue

Comment: thanks for this, I ended up just making the UIView a delegate and then having it called in the UIViewController and then access the segue that way.

Comment: @OliBlack i'm so very confused. Are you telling me that the issue was the xib is being used inside the `storyboard` on a `UIViewController` and you didn't know how to access the parent to call the segue? That is not at all what your question asked. Please be clearer next time

Answer (score 0):

You could put a ViewController into the Storyboard, set the class to your custom ViewController. Then, if you have class files for the view in the xib, set your custom view as the VC's view (already saves some code in loadView) and then just add a segue from the custom VC to the other view controller. To trigger that segue, you have to call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifierOfSegue"]` in your custom ViewController.

Comment: It is not a ViewController that is my custom view, it is a custom UIView there is no controller

Comment: "And then a class that controls the view" - is that not a view controller?

Comment: That other answer, there the programmatic presentation must also be in a ViewController... That's why you get the error.